# Can setDefaultCloseOperation work without specifying any object?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I came across a code which calls setdefaultcloseoperation() without reference to any object. I read that methods are called with reference to object. Here is the code

```
public class Mainpage extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Mainpage");

    public Mainpage() {
        super("Mainpage");
        f.setSize(1000,6000);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // how is this happening?
}
```

I want to know how `setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` is working. Thanks.

Comment: this code created two JFrames, one is extends JFrame second JFrame f=new JFrame("Mainpage");,

Comment: `**setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);**` is valid for `Mainpage extends JFrame implements ActionListener{` and never will be visible (in this code snipped), do you understand now what, why, where and how :-)

Comment: good :-), don't forget to upvote answers and accept nicer from answer :-)

Comment: +1 for real question, event bad described (but only on 1st sight)

Comment: I will bake care of that next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you extended `JFrame`. So in essence you are doing `this.setDefaultOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`.

Also it doesn't make sense that you are creating a `JFrame` inside a `JFrame`.. unless this was an experiment of yours. Simple answer would be don't extend JFrame, and use 
`f.setDefaultOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`.

Answer (score 4):

The method `setDefaultCloseOperation` refers to the current instance of `JFrame`.

---

Some side notes:

1) The second `JFrame` `f` is unnecessary here:

```
public class Mainpage extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public Mainpage(){
   super("Mainpage");
   setSize(1000,6000);
   ...
   setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setVisible(true);
}
```

2) Avoid using the `null` layout. See [Doing Without a Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).